# Mocking Record.insert() in jooq()

Tags: java, unit-testing, jooq

I have a controller end point that looks something like so

```
@POST
public JobComponentGetResponse createJobComponent(
    @PathParam("jobId") Integer jobId,
    @Valid JobComponentPostRequest request
) {
    JobComponentRecord newJobComponent = dao.jobComponent.newRecord();

    newJobComponent.setJobId(jobId);
    newJobComponent.setLabel(request.label);
    newJobComponent.setSqft(request.sqFt);

    newJobComponent.insert();

    return new JobComponentGetResponse(newJobComponent);
}
```

And a corresponding unit test

```
@Test
public void createJobComponent_createsAndReturnsTheDesiredRecord() {
    JobComponentPostRequest request = new JobComponentPostRequest();
    JobComponentRecord jobComponent = spy(new JobComponentRecord());
    when(dao.jobComponent.newRecord()).thenReturn(jobComponent);

    when(jobComponent.insert()).thenReturn(null);

    JobComponentGetResponse response = jobComponentController.createJobComponent(jobId, request);

    assertThat(response, samePropertyValuesAs(request));
}
```

I'm trying to test the response of my controller but I keep getting a null pointer exception when the controller calls `newJobComponent.insert()`

I've tried doing `when(jobComponent.insert()).thenReturn(null);` and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your dao.jobComponent.newRecord() returns null even if you do : `when(dao.jobComponent.newRecord()).thenReturn(jobComponent);`

What is dao.jobComponent exactly and where does it comes from ?

**EDIT :** I don't have a full overview of your code but a getter for JobComponentRecord  would be a good idea and you could easily determine his return value with mockito.

Comment: the weird part is that `newJobComponent` is not null it's of type `JobComponentRecord.Mockito.Mock` and all the setters work fine. It's only when it runs the `insert` it throws a null pointer.